# problem with asp.net website project

Tags: asp.net, web

I've an asp.net web site project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. the thing is that i need it all to copy to a flash drive, and than later to open it as simple in browsers/
I published my project to my drive, and tried to open my .aspx pages with Internet Explorer but i got some error. I really need to do it, urgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somojon: You can't just open an asp.net page using a browser without having the web server (IIS, most of the time) process the page and spit out HTML that can be rendered on a browser.

You can copy the whole project (as Mrchief said) to your flash drive but before you attempt to open the project from your flash drive, you need to copy it again to a computer and configure IIS (or another web server that has support for ASP.NET).

I imagine you think you can do this because you can run your project with Visual Studio, but that's because Visual Studio comes with an the integrated web server that process the ASP .NET code and spits out the HTML to display on your browser. Bottom line is that when you move your project to another computer you will need a web server to serve your ASP .NET pages.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the entire solution folder. Publish is not going to help because that  publishes files that are needed to run the site, not the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work, you should have a web server to run your ASP.NET website, IIS, IIS Express or other ASP.NET compatible web server which should execute the compiled assemblies and serve the pages to the browser.

if you simply open the pages with a browser without having a server processing them, nothing executes.